# Unnecessary SELECT by Hibernate with second level cache

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, ehcache, jpa-2.1

In the TestApplication class, I save a JPA entity 3 times using a Spring Data JPA repository backed by Hibernate configured with a second level cache.

On the first save, a SQL INSERT is issued by Hibernate.
On the second save, two SQL queries are issued by Hibernate : a SELECT and an UPDATE.
Finally, on the third save, only a SQL UPDATE is issued by Hibernate.

Why do I have the SELECT query during the second save?
The entity should already be in the second level cache after the first save and the second save should behave like the third save.

Test.java :

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Test {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String value;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }    
}
```

TestRepository.java :

```
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<Test, Long> {
}
```

TestApplication.java :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext = SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
        TestRepository testRepository = configurableApplicationContext.getBean(TestRepository.class);

        Test test = new Test();
        test.setValue("test1");
        LOGGER.info("Save 1");
        testRepository.save(test);

        test.setValue("test2");
        LOGGER.info("Save 2");
        testRepository.save(test);

        test.setValue("test3");
        LOGGER.info("Save 3");
        testRepository.save(test);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
spring.jpa.database: H2
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Run log :

```
2015-07-07 10:53:33.865  INFO 3220 --- [           main] fr.test.TestApplication                  : Save 1
2015-07-07 10:53:33.950 DEBUG 3220 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into test (id, value) values (null, ?)
2015-07-07 10:53:34.002  INFO 3220 --- [           main] fr.test.TestApplication                  : Save 2
2015-07-07 10:53:34.029 DEBUG 3220 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select test0_.id as id1_0_0_, test0_.value as value2_0_0_ from test test0_ where test0_.id=?
2015-07-07 10:53:34.083 DEBUG 3220 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : update test set value=? where id=?
2015-07-07 10:53:34.094  INFO 3220 --- [           main] fr.test.TestApplication                  : Save 3
2015-07-07 10:53:34.097 DEBUG 3220 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : update test set value=? where id=?
```